# Como crear un POD para un nodo. Kubernetes

Tags: server, kubernetes, yaml

He intentando crear un pod y me da problemas al intentar incluirlo en mi nodo. Soy nuevo en todo esto de servidores.

Mí código es este:

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Pod

metadata: 
  name: pod-try
  namespace: pruebas
  labels:
    app: pod_prueba

spec:
  containers: 
   name: prueba_pod
   image: redis
```

El mensaje de error es el siguiente: ***"Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "pod_try.yml": Pod in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Pod: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field PodSpec.spec.containers of type []v1.Container"***

El detalle es que ya antes había insertado Pods en este nodo y todo bien al incluirlos. Este es la excepción.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `containers` debería ser una lista. Esto debería funcionarte:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1

kind: Pod

metadata: 
  name: pod-try
  namespace: pruebas
  labels:
    app: pod_prueba

spec:
  containers: 
  - name: prueba_pod
    image: redis
```